# How to install SQL Server 2008 32 bit to Windows 2003 Server 64 bit?

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to install SQL Server 2008 32 bit to Windows 2003 Server 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

Run setup.exe

You can run 32 but programs on 64 bit OS normally. I'm typing this in 32 bit Opera on Windows 7 x64.

It's only where you need drivers (mostly) that you need x64 code to match

From the [SQL Server MSDN Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx), look at OS requirements for "SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard (32-bit)"

Answer (score 0):

Install all your prerequirements and then run the setup file in the x86 folder. If you run the setup in the root folder it will choose the architecture for you.